# Feriale e festivo: sinonimi o contrari?

Tags: word-meaning, word-choice, etymology, adjectives

È la prima volta che uso questo sito, quindi scusate la domanda forse sciocca.

Per distinguere i giorni della settimana si possono usare gli aggettivi "*feriale*" per indicare i giorni lavorativi (dal lunedì al venerdì) mentre "*festivo*" per il fine settimana ossia sabato e domenica.

Ma come mai si usano due sinonimi per indicare due concetti che sono "contrari"?

Per curiosità, ci sono altri esempi di sinonimi che acquisiscono accezioni contrarie in base al contesto in cui vengono usati?

Comment: 1) in che senso feriale e sinonimo di festivo? 2) sabato e un pre-festivo.

Comment: In questa distinzione di giorni settimanali il termine feriale significa "non festivo"....

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Trovi una spiegazione molto dettagliata sull'etimologia di "ferie" e "feriale" in questo [articolo di Maurizio Trifone](https://www.academia.edu/42115999/Maurizio_Trifone_Dal_latino_all_italiano_una_storia_di_parole): «Interessante è il caso di *ferie* e *feriale*, due latinismi che sono attestati fin dal 
Trecento e che, pur essendo strettamente imparentati, hanno significati antitetici: il 
sostantivo equivale a ‘periodo di vacanza’ (*andare in ferie*), l’aggettivo è sinonimo di ‘lavorativo, non festivo’ (*giorno feriale*). Per spiegare questa apparente [...]».

Comment: @Hachi: Credo che l'OP si riferisca a "feria" come "giorno di vacanza" (cioè, giorno in certo senso "festivo" per la persona che gode di queste vacanze). Vedi il mio commento precedente.

Comment: “ci sono altri esempi di sinonimi che acquisiscono accezioni contrarie”: ci sono esempi così, o addirittura della stessa parola che può avere sensi quasi opposti (pensa a “ospite”). È proprio quello della domanda, però, che _non_ è un esempio così. “Feriale” è il contrario di festivo, per nulla un sinonimo.

Comment: Grazie a tutti per aver capito quello che volevo dire. Grazie anche per le risposte davvero interessanti che mi avete dato

Comment: In riferimento all'ultima domanda ("*Per curiosità, ci sono altri esempi di sinonimi che acquisiscono accezioni contrarie in base al contesto in cui vengono usati?*"), se ho capito bene cosa intendi, sì ci sono vocaboli che, in determinati ambiti, acquistano significati opposti; si chiama **enantiosemia**. Alcuni esempi li puoi trovare qui: https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enantiosemia#Esempi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nel linguaggio comune il sabato non è un giorno festivo, in generale. E non vedo “sinonimi”. Le parole *ferie* e *feriale* hanno un'etimologia comune, ma hanno assunto significati divergenti.

La storia è complicata, ma non troppo. In latino, *feria* indicava un giorno dedicato al culto, nel quale non era possibile tenere udienze giudiziarie o convocare i comizi. Da questo significato discendono le nostre *ferie* (sempre plurale).

Nel mondo ecclesiastico, si cercò di evitare di nominare i nomi dei giorni della settimana con gli dei pagani, com'era l'uso diffuso nel mondo romano quando si adottarono le settimane e fino alle riforme seguite al Concilio Vaticano II, con l'introduzione delle lingue volgari, i messali in latino nominavano i giorni della settimana come

*dominica, feria secunda, feria tertia, feria quarta, feria quinta, feria sexta, sabbato*

anche perché essenzialmente ogni giorno era dedicato a qualche santo. In portoghese i nomi della settimana si chiamano ancora così, solo con adattamenti linguistici

*domingo, segunda-feira, terça-feira, quarta-feira, quinta-feira, sexta-feira, sábado*

Da quest'uso segue quello di *giorno feriale* per indicare un giorno della settimana diverso dalla domenica.

In francese, *jour férié* significa giorno festivo.

Fonti: [dizionario Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/feria/) e [Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/ferie-e-feriale/72)

Per un altro esempio di parole con etimologia comune ma significati diversi, si può considerare *zero* e *cifra*. Entrambi vengono dall'arabo *ṣifr* che è il termine arabo per zero. Quando Fibonacci descrisse il sistema di numerazione indiano (appreso dagli arabi durante il suo soggiorno nell'attuale Tunisia) nel suo *Liber abaci*, aveva bisogno di una nuova parola per indicare la cifra zero e adottò *zephirus*, una parola latina che assomigliasse a quella araba. Da *zefiro* si passò presto a *zero* in italiano e da qui si diffuse in Europa con questa forma. Ma *ṣifr*, per altra via, divenne *cifra*.

Comment: Da notare che l'uso di feria in questo senso (giorno dove non c'è alcuna particolare solennità religiosa) è ancora presente nel calendario liturgico (dove le ferie sono contrapposte alle feste e alle solennità)

Comment: Tutto molto interessante, ma l’affermazione che feriale sia sinonimo di festivo è errata nell’italiano corrente.

Comment: @Hachi Non mi pare di averlo scritto.

Comment: No, ma e’ il presupposto su cui si basa  la domanda.

Comment: Ti ringrazio @egreg, questo era proprio quello che cercavo.

Answer (score 0):

Aggiungo alla risposta di @egreg quello che si trova nell'articolo ["Dal latino all’italiano: una storia di parole"](https://www.academia.edu/42115999/Maurizio_Trifone_Dal_latino_all_italiano_una_storia_di_parole) di Maurizio Trifone:

> Interessante è il caso di *ferie* e *feriale*, due latinismi che sono attestati fin dal Trecento e che, pur essendo strettamente imparentati, hanno significati antitetici: il sostantivo equivale a ‘periodo di vacanza’ (*andare in ferie*), l’aggettivo è sinonimo di ‘lavorativo, non festivo’ (*giorno feriale*). Per spiegare questa apparente contraddizione
> bisogna risalire a una variazione di significato che il latino FĒRIAE ha subito in ambito ecclesiastico. Il latino classico FĒRIAE , da avvicinare a FĔSTUS ‘festivo’, indicava i giorni festivi, in cui ci si asteneva dal lavoro. In epoca tarda il singolare FĒRIA passa a designare nella liturgia cristiana i giorni della settimana, dal lunedì al venerdì, distinti da un numerale ordinale progressivo: poiché il calendario cristiano enumera i giorni partendo dalla domenica, FĒRIA SECŬNDA (o SECŬNDA FĒRIA ) era il ‘lunedì’, FĒRIA
> TĔRTIA il ‘martedì’, FĒRIA QUĂRTA il ‘mercoledì’, FĒRIA QUĪNTA il ‘giovedì’, FĒRIA SĔXTA il ‘venerdì’. Tali denominazioni si affiancano a quelle usate dagli Ebrei di Roma, che contavano i giorni della settimana dal giorno successivo al sabato e usavano un numero progressivo + SĂBBATI : SECŬNDA SĂBBATI equivaleva perciò a SECŬNDA FĒRIA ,
> TĔRTIA SĂBBATI a TĔRTIA FĒRIA e così via. Questi usi avevano lo scopo di evitare che i giorni della settimana fossero chiamati con nomi di tradizione pagana, i quali peraltro sono sopravvissuti fino ai giorni nostri. Ad eccezione del portoghese che si rifà al calendario cristiano (*segunda-feira* ‘lunedì’, *terça-feira* ‘martedì’, ecc.), tutte le lingue romanze conservano traccia del paganesimo con i nomi dei giorni della settimana dai corpi celesti del sistema solare<sup>114</sup>. Del resto anche il sabato e la domenica, prima dell’avvento del cristianesimo, avevano denominazioni di origine pagana che furono poi sostituite conformemente al programma di cristianizzazione dell’impero romano attuato nel IV secolo dagli imperatori Costantino e Teodosio. Il risultato è che la nostra settimana è «una specie di compromesso fra tre diversi sistemi (sistema planetario
> pagano, sistema ebraico e sistema cristiano)» (Tagliavini 1963: 74). L’italiano *ferie* continua il significato del latino classico FĒRIAE , mentre l’aggettivo *feriale* si ricollega al significato che il latino tardo FĒRIA ha assunto con il cristianesimo, vale a dire ‘giorno della settimana’ diverso dalla domenica: il DĬES DOMĬNICUS (o DĬES DOMĬNICA), dedicato al Signore, è il giorno festivo per eccellenza; il DĬES FERIĂLIS , ogni altro giorno
> della settimana, dedicato alla celebrazione di un santo, è non festivo e quindi è un giorno lavorativo (Tagliavini 1963: 67-69). Il latino tardo FĒRIA ha avuto anche un altro
> sviluppo semantico: poiché nei giorni festivi era usanza fare mercati e fiere intorno alle chiese, FĒRIA assume il significato di ‘giorno di mercato’ e ‘mercato’, da cui l’italiano
> *fiera* (con metatesi di *i*), il francese *foire*, il catalano *fira*.
>
>  ------------------- 
> <sup>114. DĬE(M) LŪNAE ‘giorno della Luna’ > italiano *lunedì*, francese *lundi*, spagnolo *lunes*, rumeno *luni*; DĬE(M) MĀRTIS ‘giorno di Marte’ > italiano *martedì*, francese *mardi*, spagnolo *martes*, rumeno *marți*; DĬE(M) MERCŬRI
> ‘giorno di Mercurio’ > italiano *mercoledì*, francese *mercredi*, spagnolo *miércoles*, rumeno *miercuri*; DĬE(M) IŎVIS ‘giorno di Giove’ > italiano *giovedì*, francese *jeudi*, spagnolo *jueves*, rumeno *joi*; DĬE(M) VĔNERIS ‘giorno di Venere’ > italiano *venerdì*, francese *vendredi*, spagnolo *viernes*, rumeno *vineri*.</sup>

A tutto questo, io aggiungerei il catalano: DĬE(M) LŪNAE > *dilluns*, DĬE(M) MĀRTIS > *dimarts*, DĬE(M) MERCŬRI > *dimecres*, DĬE(M) IŎVIS > *dijous*, DĬE(M) VĔNERIS > *divendres*.